# Not able to connect to internet using Android Emulator?

Tags: android

i'm not able to connect my android emulator to net
i am using 2.3 API based system
i am having permission in manifesto file.
i am using broadband to connect to internet,i connect directly to net
i am using windows xp service pack 2
what is my emulators problem?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: i check that no use...i am not using any proxy...

Answer (score 1):

In order to use internet on emulator if you are setting behind a proxy server perform the following steps:

Go to settings->Wireless & networks->mobile networks->Access Point Names.
Press menu button. an option menu will appear.

from the option menu select New APN.

Click on Name. provide name to apn say My APN.
Click on APN. Enter www.

After this check the internet.